# MySQL: Count rows based on fields name.( Part-2 )

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql table:

**Defects**

```
df_id | project_id | resp_id | status
------+------------+---------+----------
1     |     1      |    1    |  Open 
2     |     1      |    1    |  Open
3     |     1      |    1    |  Closed
4     |     1      |    2    |  Open
5     |     1      |    2    |  Closed
```

**Responsible**

```
resp_id | resp_comp_name
--------+----------------
   1    |     Google
   2    |     Firefox
```

and I require output

```
resp_comp_name | open | closed
---------------+------+--------
  Google       |  3   |    1
  Firefox      |  1   |    1
```

I wrote:

```
     SELECT r.resp_comp_name, d.status, COUNT(d.df_id) AS total
       FROM pms_defects d
  LEFT JOIN pms_responsibles r ON d.resp_id=r.resp_id
      WHERE d.project_id='1' AND d.resp_id != 0
   GROUP BY d.resp_id
   ORDER BY total DESC
```

it produce:

[image]

Comment: That's a good story. What would you like us to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT r.resp_comp_name, sum(if(d.status = 'Open',1,0)) as open, 
sum(if(d.status ='Closed',1,0)) as closed from pms_defects d, pms_responsibles r 
where r.resp_id = d.resp_id group by d.resp_id
```

This uses if statements and sum to move open/closed from row- to column-based.